# Create a teardrop like css shape without rotation and with an image as background

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to create a css shape like this (I don't know the name for that shape) and also add a background image to it. Can you guys help me?

Here is the shape:

```css
.figure{
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #32557f;
    border-radius: 0 50% 0% 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    bottom: -50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 17px
  }
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>
```

If I attach a background image it is also affected by the rotation.

```css
.figure{
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #32557f;
    border-radius: 0 50% 0% 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634315-48f5414c3ad9');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    bottom: -50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 17px
  }
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>
```

---

Ok my current solution looks like this:

```css
  .figure {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #32557f;
    border-radius: 0 50% 0% 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    bottom: -50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  

  .test{
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602000750546-f8e331a082d1);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 145%;
    width: 142%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -43px;
    right: -44px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="figure">
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how to call this css shape?

Thank you!

Comment: I think we should assume that turning the image around in Paint isn't an option here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `img` instead of `background-image` and counteract the rotation with `transform: rotate(-45deg)`:

```css
.figure {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #32557f;
  border-radius: 0 50% 0% 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: -50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  height: 142%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-39%);
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634315-48f5414c3ad9" />
</div>
```

---

Another option is to use `clip-path` with an `svg`:

```css
img {
  height: 260px;
  clip-path: url(#teardrop);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634315-48f5414c3ad9" />

<svg>
    <clipPath id="teardrop">
        <path
            d="M88.49 0C121.05 32.57 141.41 52.92 149.55 61.06C186.12 97.63 186.12 156.93 149.55 193.5C141.41 201.64 121.05 221.99 88.49 254.56C55.92 221.99 35.57 201.64 27.43 193.5C-9.14 156.93 -9.14 97.63 27.43 61.06C35.57 52.92 55.92 32.57 88.49 0Z"
        ></path>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! And is there a way to let the image cover the entire space. I have tried with width, height and background-size but it looks not really nice and if I have Images that change maybe once a week it will be hard to allways fit them manually.

Comment: If the container is always 180px then my edit should work. Another option is to rotate the source image -45deg so you don't have to use any CSS. I'm guessing as the image changes often that's not feasible?

Comment: I've added another way you could do it using `clip-path`